# Does dreamweaver CS5 have a way to hyperlink CSS classes like Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: css, sharepoint, class, dreamweaver, sharepoint-designer

I've been using SharePoint Designer for yrs now at my job and just recently started using Dreamweaver CS5.

In SP Designer, any class names or ID's tied to a class will automatically create a hyperlink straight to the .css file (takes you to the exact line). This little shortcut saves a ton of time and makes coding so much faster. I've looked everywhere in my settings, online and just cannot find this option.

Does anyone know if this is possible in CS5???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Macintosh, the way to do that is to Command/Option click on the HTML code. Then the CSS will pop up and you can click the CSS there. The page will pop up where it is located.

On a PC I am sure it is something very similar, Ctl/? click maybe?